# How do we say, "issue a new identity card" in Italian?

Tags: verbs, translation

I lost my identity card a few days ago and need to have a new one issued. What is the Italian verb for "issue" in this case?

Comment: Is the verb you are looking for "[rilasciare](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carta_d'identit%C3%A0_italiana)"? [Also here](http://www.esteri.it/mae/it/italiani_nel_mondo/serviziconsolari/documenti_di_viaggio/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper translation of the verb "to issue" is "rilasciare", so you would say:

"Devo farmi rilasciare una nuova carta d'identità".

However, commonly you would use the active form, saying, for example:

"Devo richiedere una nuova carta di identità" (formal)

or just:

"Devo rifare la carta di identità" (informal and normally used while speaking)

"Rifare" is a verb which is mostly used in informal contexts and which means "fare di nuovo" (to do again).

Comment: It seems that you are translating the verb "to request", not the verb "to issue".

Comment: @randomaltabuser Yes, but normally you wouldn't say "Devo farmi rilasciare una nuova carta d'identità"; you would the active form and user one of the two I proposed. But yes, "rilasciare" is, technically speaking, more correct. Thanks for noting, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 8):

The correct translation is "rilasciare".
In your example: "Pochi giorni fa ho smarrito la carta di identità e devo farmene rilasciare una nuova."

Answer (score -1):

> “issue a new identity card”

`Rilasciare una nuova carta d'identità`

**But**

> "need to have a new one issued"

There's not a word by word translation form "a new one issued". You should use the active form like this

`Ho perso la carta di identità, devo richiederne una nuova.`

Comment: "need to have a new one issued" can be translates "devo farmi rilasciare una nuova carta di identitá". Although that sounds convoluted